# Setting system PATH like so : export PATH=$PATH:/../play Play Framework on Linux fails

Tags: java, linux, path, playframework, playframework-2.0

This is in a Mint15 distro. I have removed SoX as it conflicted with the global play using the commmand...

```
sudo aptitude remove '?name(sox)'
```

, and can get my Play Framework to fire up, only if I add the command

```
export PATH=$PATH:/relPath/play
```

**every time**, before executing `play`. I would think this installs play into my system PATH, but it seems to be temporary. (i.e. I exit terminal, then open and play, it fails)

I have tried this as root and regular user. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add

```
export PATH=$PATH:/relPath/play
```

to your ~/.bashrc.

Comment: sudo vim ~/.bashrc did not work, but vim ~/.bashrc did... thanks.